# Mysql - wierd join query

Tags: mysql, subquery

Is it possible in MySQL to join a?

For example, say I have the following sub query:

```
select username, password from users
```

I want to use the fields in an update as follows:

```
update test_users set password = { result from subquery } where { result from subquery.user } = 100;
```

This is a silly example but only used to illustrate the point.

Essentially my sub query returns two columns and I need to use them in an update.

Comment: Can you provide more information about your 2 table that you wish to use the data from ? It looks like you can do what you want with a simple JOIN but unless you provide more information will be hard to tell you the best way.

Comment: You can join the subquery and use its columns.

Comment: I want to persist the data though.  So still need to do the update.

Comment: you can use that condition ie... where { result from subquery.user } = 100; in subquey itself ...  then you can use query as "update test_users set password = { result from subquery }"

Comment: @MartyWallace - `update yourtable a join (select col1, col2 from xyz) sub on a.id = sub.id where sub.col1 = 1 and sub.col2=3` - something along those lines, I'm typing it quickly and haven't checked at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can also store selected fields in the variables:

```
SELECT login, password FROM sometable INTO @login, @password
UPDATE othertable SET password = @password WHERE login = @login
```